# Could not find getter for Component member

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

We're using Fluent Nhibernate and I can't seem to map a component. My component class isn't an entity and has two values:

```
 public class Member
 {
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
 }
```

The parent entity is mapped to a view with two columns to fill the two properties. I map the class as a component using Linq as:

```
Component(x => x.CurrentMember, m =>
{
    m.Map(x => x.ID, "MemberId");
    m.Map(x => x.Name, "MemberName");
});
```

When I run this I get FluentNHibernateConfigurationException building the SessionFactory: "Could not find a getter for property 'ID' in class 'Member". This isn't an entity so I'm a little confused as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your class doesn't specify a property called `ID` - it specifies a field. Perhaps you should try giving your class properties rather than public fields:

```
public class Member
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As @andronz mentions below they need to be virtual properties.

Comment: @ColeW: Definitely virtual? Even though this isn't an entity? Will edit to mention that, but I'd try without first :)

Comment: That did it, I didn't realize component properties also had to be virtual. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon, Actually you are right.  Virtual is un-needed within the component. Only in the entity itself.

Comment: @IRegretable: Given Cole's latest comment, have you tried the first version? (i.e. properties, but non-virtual)

Comment: @Jon, I've tested both ways and it definitely works without the properties being virtual in the component.

Answer (score 2):

maybe try to use property, which should be virtual